# Beginner error Python and Atom

Tags: python, atom-editor

Having trouble with Python code in Atom. I'm using 'Learn Python The Hard Way' to practice some coding. When I enter this code into Atom, there is no error but it just won't run (yes, I have Script installed and it works fine for other things). There is a little egg timer in the bottom of Atom but nothing else gives me any indication of what I may be doing wrong.

```
print "How old are you?",
age = raw_input()
print "How tall are you?",
height = raw_input()
print "How much do you weigh?",
weight = raw_input()

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight)
```

When I type like this

```
print "How old are you?",
print "How tall are you?",
print "How much do you weigh?",

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy." % (
    age, height, weight)
```

The code runs, but with an error just saying that age is not defined and that makes sense because the code isn't complete. Does that just show that there is no problem with the editor but with the code? So please help. I'm new to this.

Comment: What is your question exactly? I can see that you installed Atom, and that you ran a piece of code. But I'm not sure what you mean when  you say, "there is no error but it just wont run" and then later say, "the code runs but with an error saying that age is not defined". Note that Atom is just a text editor it will not run the code for you. You must run the code through a terminal or command prompt.

Comment: @PrestonHager They're attempting to run the code with a plugin called script, which allows you to execute code inside of Atom. They don't necessarily need to run it in a terminal if they're using script.

Comment: The first code fragment _runs_, but it waits for you to type something. That is why you should _never_ call `raw_input()` without the parameter.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense, thanks @Will. Though I'm still not sure what the question is. And it's still safer to run it without a plugin, outside of the editor environment, plus it makes it easier to debug, at least in Python.

Comment: The second code you paste, you need get the user input value and storage  to a variable, after do this, you can run you code. You first  paste code is good sample.

Comment: I notice you're using python 2. Since you're new to python, I highly recommend you use/learn python 3 instead of python 2. The only reason to use python 2 these days is if your company hasn't updated to python 3 and they're forcing you to use python 2.

Comment: I recommend you use an "actual" python interpreter. Atom is more like a text editor than an interpreter.

Comment: abccd - which interpreter do you recommend ?

Answer (score 2):

The [script](https://atom.io/packages/script) package does not handle collecting input. If your script requires input (as your first script does), then it will just sit and wait.

Your second script doesn't expect any input, so it runs (but then, as you see, it has an error due to `age` not being defined).

The author of the script package has suggested ([here](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/280) and [here](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/issues/511)) that [Hydrogen](https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen) may be an alternative if you need to handle input.

Answer (score -1):

Try following

print "So, you're " + str(age) + " old, " + str(height) + " tall and " + str(weight) + " heavy."

Comment: That's not going to solve a `NameError`. The problem is that in the problem script, `age`, `height` and `weight` are not defined.

Comment: That error is for second script where she is not defining any variable. She has a question regarding first script And second script is just given for reference, Isn't it???

Comment: In the first script, `raw_input` returns a string, so explicitly calling `str` on those returned strings does nothing.

Comment: Agree with you, David.